# ¿Error de consulta controladores de API en JAVASCRIPT? Error campo email y dirección de residencia

Tags: javascript, c#, vb.net, web

El problema es el siguiente:

Estoy cargando unos campos tipo label de correo electrónico y dirección de residencia desde una página web  en vb.net, estoy haciendo una consulta de información a ver si estos datos existen en nuestra base de datos, y me retorne unos datos de estos campos, es como un tipo de filtro. Estos datos se envían por Ajax de javascript al controlador respectivo.

Pero lo que paso es que cuando los envió al API mediante un método "GET", me retorna error, y visualizó la consola y se debe a que me está colocando caracteres que yo no enviado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me toca mostrar el error en foto porque por escrito no me deja me los oculta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se alguien me pueda ayudar a ver porque se me crean estos caracteres o como de otra manera puede enviar los campos de correo y dirección, no se si por los simbolos de "@" o "#" que me están molestando.

Muchas Gracias y quedo atento a la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Porque hay caracteres que no son soportados en la codificación de URLs y por eso se cambian a sus equivalentes en un proceso de "sanitización" que hacen todos los clientes y servidores web.

Cuando el servidor hace la interpretación (parseo) del URL re-convierte esos elementos a sus caracteres originales. Si esto no sucede, debes buscar algún método que lo haga por ti.

Para mas info: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP